# how to center two textViews with different font-size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_information"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.17"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\@ Home in"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to center the two textViews vertically,

but I want them to be aligned to one line at their bottom.

Now they are alined to the same bottom,

but they are at the bottom of their parent layout.

How can I do this?

I have thought to wrap their current layout parent ("parent1") with another layout 
("parent2")

and make "parent1" be in the center of "parent2".

Is there another way without adding elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your problem is that both views are aligned at the bottom of their parent you can use this. 
Both views are still aligned to the same bottom and centered on the screen.

Your layout looks like a part of a bigger XML (weight=0.17), that is why I have used fill_parent on layout_width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_information"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.17"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_destination"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="\@ Home in"
    android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:text="\@ Home in"
    android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_view_destination"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/text_view_destination" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the second `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` is redundant, no?

Comment: i read `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html but still didn't understand what this means.

Comment: With relativeLayout you can use some attributes on his childs view allowing you to position it where you need. layout_alignParentBottom is like 'align this view within his parent to the bottom area' so if the parent is a square it will go to the bottom area, android:layout_alignParentLeft 'align this view within his parent to the left area', and so on.

Comment: but I don't want the text to be at the bottom area of its parent. on the contrary, that's what I have today and I want to change. So why did you put this? anyway I see another result: the two text are in the middle and have the same baseline

Comment: the second android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" is redundant, no?

Comment: @EladBenda You're right, it's an old post but I made an edit to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_information"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HOme in"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Home out"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why do we need `android:layout_weight="1"` ?

Comment: android:gravity="center_vertical|bottom" makes no sense